# Check if variable is equal to rules in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to check if a variable informed by the user is equal to some existing rules, for example:

I have the following rules

```
general(mammal) :- facts.
general(bird) :- facts.
```

then i do

```
read(X).
```

and I want to check if X is equal to either mammal or bird. Is there a way to do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. E.g.

```
read(X), (X=mammal ; X=bird).
```

The semicolon represents logical disjunction (OR operator), and brackets are there for the sake of ensuring the right order of goals. 
In case X is instantiated to mammal or bird, it will have that value, otherwise it will be false.

Edit:
if I understand correctly, you want:

```
read(X), general(X).
```

Prolog will find X such that its goals are met, and then proceed to goal `general(X)`. In case X is mammal or bird, Prolog will match the goal with one of the general clauses, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: But I want the program to do it automatically. I want it to check in every general rule if X is equal to it's "name"